# How to have show error and not allow two inputs to be submitted in form PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

One my form I have the option to choose from a select box, or to manually enter the information.

I want to prevent user from entering both. They should either choose from the select OR enter manually if their selection is not already there.

**html code**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="selectComplvl" class="regions" >Region</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <select class="form-control regionbox" id="region" value="" name="region">
                        <option>---Select---</option>
                        <?php
                          $region_sql = "SELECT * FROM `regions`";
                          $region_res = mysqli_query($con, $region_sql);
                          if(mysqli_num_rows($region_res) > 0){
                             while($region_row = mysqli_fetch_array($region_res)){
                                  echo "<option value='".$region_row[id]."'>".$region_row[region]."</option>";
                              } 
                          }

                        ?>

                      </select>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="feisEntered" class="feis">Feis Entered</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <select class="form-control feisbox" id="feisEntered" name="feisEntered">
                        <option>First choose a Region</option>

                      </select>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="feisEntered" class="enterfeis">Or Enter</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input id="inputfeis" type="text" name="feisEntered" class="form-control" placeholder="Feis name - MM/DD/YYYY">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**And my query:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
    $dancer=$_POST['dancer'];
    $dancer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$dancer);
    $level=$_POST['level'];
    $level = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$level);
    $feisEntered=$_POST['feisEntered'];
    $feisEntered = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$feisEntered);
    $danceName=$_POST['danceName'];
    $danceName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$danceName);
    $compNum=$_POST['compNum'];
    $compNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$compNum);
    $competitor = $_POST['competitor'];
    $competitor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$competitor);
    $danceScore = $_POST['danceScore'];
    $danceScore = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$danceScore);
    $placement = $_POST['placement'];
    $placement = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$placement);
    $firstScore = $_POST['firstScore'];
    $firstScore = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$firstScore);
    $secondScore = $_POST['secondScore'];
    $secondScore = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$secondScore);
    $thirdScore = $_POST['thirdScore'];
    $thirdScore = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$thirdScore);
    $judge = $_POST['judge'];
    $judge = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$judge);
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$comments);


$query = "INSERT INTO reports (user_id, dancer_id1, dancer_name, competition_level1, feis_entered, dance_name1, competition_number1, number_competitors1, dancer_score1, dancer_placement1, firstpl_score1, 2ndpl_score1, 3rdpl_score1, judge_name1, judge_comment1) VALUES ('$id','$dancerID', '$dancer', '$level', '$feisEntered', '$danceName', '$compNum', '$competitor', '$danceScore', '$placement', '$firstScore', '$secondScore', '$thirdScore', '$judge', '$comments')";

     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

So what I want to happen is a error message appears if they fill out both saying "Please choose only one". That way only one enters into database.

Comment: First, I would make sure they're not required fields in the db. You can use some JS to clear the manual entries when they choose options or vise versa.

Comment: @Mustafa How can I do that? I am not well versed in JS. Or do you have any links you can share that I can read up on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never rely on just JS to validate input. Use JS to implement the behavior you speak of and then handle all possible outcomes in PHP. If someone is fiddling with your JS and bypasses the behavior you implement, you need to be able to handle that in your PHP code as well to make sure DB doesnt get unexpected input and break everything. Just like Justin said above, you could select one or the other, or throw an error. I recommend throwing an error and telling the user to make sure they have JS enabled.

Comment: This is what I tried to do if($feisName != ""){
              $feisName = $feisname;
              
          }else {
              $feisName = $feisEntered;
          }
But It is not working at all. Only one of them gets entered into the database, and it is always the second one. I am guessing it is because the variable is getting rewritten. But I am not sure how else to go about this.

Comment: @TaahiraCarter If that "if" statement evaluated to true--you'd just be making $feisname equal to itself. If $feisName is not equal to "" (an empty string) then... make $feisName equal to itself. It's already equal to itself ^_^ so that would be redundant. Your else statement would only fire if feisName is an empty string (with no whitespace) Could you perhaps update your code in your question body with what you added so I can see where and where $feisName is created? When looking up top I don't see a $feisName. I see $feisEntered though.

Comment: Sorry it too me so long to reply, but thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML document, you should use Javascript to validate the user input before submitting the form to the PHP script. Then, in the PHP script, you should double-check that values were not received for both the select and the input (this could happen if the user does not have Javascript enabled, or they somehow bypass the validation) and determine what you want to do in that case (select one over the other, or exit with an error).